# ASP.NET Connect to database in another project through that particular project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a database project (call it DataAccess) in Visual Studio with Entity Framework 6 and a client WebAPI project (ClientProject) which needs to be able to see and use data from the database in the first project by using the the created DbContext class from the first project.

1) In order to be able to compile the two projects I had to add EF nuget package to the second project besides adding DataAccess as a reference to ClientProject. Is this the right way to do it? Shouldn't ClientProject be able to compile by using the reference from DataAccess (which already has EF) as a contract for all the available/allowed methods? It seems a little weird to have EF installed on top of both projects.

2) When use a controller in ClientProject to query resources from the database in DataAccess (via the exposed DbContext) I get 0 resources. The database table is not empty. I haven't added any extra configuration to ClientProject besides referencing DataAccess. Any ideea if I still need to do something? Maybe have a connection string to the database? I'm inclined to think not since I'm expecting all data access to be made available by DataAccess project.

Comment: About second question you are connecting to a different database. Check Web.config and/or App.config

Comment: I resorted to adding the same connectionString from DataAccess into ClientProject. While in an T-SQL query "select count(*) from Resource" returns 3, in my controller when I query FirstOrDefault() from Resource via the DbContext taken from the other project I get "null", stating that there are no resources in the table.